# Animating a series of images

Tags: java

I am animating a series of images in java. So far I able to animate without any problem. The problem occur only when I add in control(Start, Stop, etc..). When I press Start in my GUI the GUI does not show the animation only the last frame is shown after the animation has ended.

I not sure is it the threading problem or a painting problem, as I have tried a few methods and none of them worked.

Following is my code:

`public class SwingAnimation extends JPanel implements ActionListener {`

```
protected JFrame frame;
protected JLabel lblDisplay;
protected JButton BtnStart, BtnStop, BtnPause;
protected JCheckBox chkLoop;
protected Thread th;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingAnimation sa = new SwingAnimation();
}

public SwingAnimation() {
    frame = new JFrame("Animation");
    Panel panel = new Panel();

    lblDisplay = new JLabel();
    BtnStart = new JButton("Start");
    BtnStop = new JButton("Stop");
    BtnPause = new JButton("Pause");
    chkLoop = new JCheckBox("Loop");

    BtnStop.setEnabled(false);
    BtnPause.setEnabled(false);

    BtnStart.setActionCommand("start");
    BtnStop.setActionCommand("stop");
    BtnPause.setActionCommand("pause");

    panel.add(lblDisplay);
    panel.add(BtnStart);
    panel.add(BtnPause);
    panel.add(BtnStop);
    panel.add(chkLoop);
    frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //set the frame in the center of the screen
    Dimension screensize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int screen_x = (screensize.width - frame.getWidth()) / 2;
    int screen_y = (screensize.height - frame.getHeight()) / 2;
    frame.setLocation(screen_x, screen_y);

    BtnStart.addActionListener(this);
    BtnStop.addActionListener(this);
    BtnPause.addActionListener(this);
    chkLoop.addActionListener(this);
    th = new Thread();
    //ImageAnimator();
}

public void ImageAnimator() {
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 299; i++) {
            ImageIcon images = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Images\\Snap" + i + ".jpg");
            lblDisplay.setIcon(images);
            th.sleep(25);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if ("start".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
        BtnStart.setEnabled(false);
        BtnStop.setEnabled(true);
        BtnPause.setEnabled(true);
        lblDisplay.setVisible(true);
        ImageAnimator();
    } else if ("stop".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
        BtnStart.setText("Start");
        BtnStart.setEnabled(true);
        BtnStop.setEnabled(false);
        BtnPause.setEnabled(false);
        lblDisplay.setVisible(false);
        th = null;
    } else if ("pause".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
        BtnStart.setText("Resume");
        BtnStart.setEnabled(true);
        BtnStop.setEnabled(true);
        BtnPause.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: not realated to your problem but there is no need for creating the Thread saved in `th`. The `sleep` method is static and should be called as `Thread.sleep(25)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Quick Fix:**

Change ImageAnimator() like this:

```
        lblDisplay.setIcon(images);
        lblDisplay.paintImmediately(getBounds());
        th.sleep(25);
```

The problem you're having is that setting an icon does not automatically cause Swing to repaint the component onscreen. Calling paintImmediately will do that.

**General advice:**

Animation in swing is normally done using the [Swing Timer](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html). You'll notice at the moment that your UI is unresponsive - once you've started the animation, you won't be able to stop it until its over. That's because all Swing events happen on a single thread - the Event Dispatch Thread. Running a loop with Thread.sleep(...) in the middle ties this thread up, leaving it unavailable to process other input (such as pressing the stop button)

[This article](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads1.html) helped me immeasurably when I was trying to understand how Swing handles concurrency, and [The Swing Trail](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) has lots of advice on using Swing effectively, painting custom components etc.

I'd also plug the demo code on [Filthy Rich Clients](http://filthyrichclients.org/), I'm working through the book at the moment and it's worth a look.

Comment: and method names should start with a lower case letter so imageAnimator()... :)

Comment: Good call. I work with a couple of ex C++ gurus, and have gotten so used to their random approach to capitalisation, it didn't even register. :(

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but the paintImmediately() method did not work as it keeps telling me that it can't find symbol. But I'll be switching to the swing timer.

Comment: That'll teach me to double check things I've not used in a while.
I think lblDisplay.paintImmediately(lblDisplay.getBounds()) should do the trick, but you're better off on the swing timer anyway. :)

Comment: Well,lblDisplay.paintImmediately(lblDisplay.getBounds()) did not do the trick, but rather lblDisplay.paint(lblDisplay.getGraphics()) did it. But i need to let the app run once before i can see the animation.

Answer (score 1):

This [Java 2D games tutorial](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/) covers several basic animation techniques. Some related example that illustrate the techniques are cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2068517/230513), and this complete [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9852739/230513) illustrates stop and start buttons.