# Java Simple Graphic Loop is slow

Tags: java, performance, swing, java-2d, thread-sleep

Im quiet new in java graphics programming, but i didnt thougt i would have problems right at the beginning:

I have this simple loop - which moves and resizes the cube, but its very slow and "unclean". I  can see the pixels changing, when you know what i mean. What could i do better here? And why its so slow? Thank you all!

So, heres the code:

```
package game;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main extends JPanel implements Runnable{

    Box b = new Box(0, 0, 20, 20);
    Thread t = new Thread(this);

    public Main(){
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setSize(800, 600);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLayout(null);
        f.setVisible(true);

        setBounds(0, 0, f.getWidth(), f.getHeight());
        setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        f.add(this);

        t.start();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        b.paint(g);
    }

    public void run(){
        while(b.x < 100){
            b.x++;
            b.y++;
            b.width++;
            b.height++;
            repaint();
            try{Thread.sleep(10);}catch(Exception e){}
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public class Box {

        public int x;
        public int y;
        public int width;
        public int height;
        public boolean used;

        public Box(int x, int y, int width, int height){
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g){
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: do you require that `Thread.sleep`

Comment: what do you mean?.. could you explain a bit?

Comment: use `Swing Timer` instead or `Thread` and dealyed by `Thread.sleep(int)`, because `Thread.sleep(int)` caused lock of EDT, btw (maybe one milion times) asked similair questions here :-)

Comment: See this question about enabling Double Buffering (I have a feeling that's your "uncleaneliness"): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924697/java-double-buffering

Comment: @pwny Swing JComponents are DoubleBuffered by default

Comment: @mKorbel I wasn't sure about it.  Thanks for the info (the more you know!)

Comment: yes that is right... but all tutorials or videos i saw said i should use thread.sleep instead of timers.

Comment: Timer is better, Thread.sleep should be better be in a separate Thread, which again has its details to worry about. In demos it is often a matter of verbosity. Maybe `panel.repaint(50L);` too.

Comment: i dont know you actually see, but Thread.sleep is in an own thread... and i dont know how to set up an gameloop with an timer...

Comment: @trashgod OP is not sleeping on the EDT, so that's not the issue here.

Comment: @haraldK: Thanks, you are correct; GFP: Please cite the tutorial(s) to which you refer.

Comment: for example this one:
http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=24220.0

Answer (score 4):

I'd use a Swing `Timer` as mentioned in the comments, otherwise there's nothing obviously wrong with your code.

However, to get perfectly smooth graphics on screen, you need to have "vertical sync" (that is, the entire painting must be done between screen refresh). I suggest you have a look at [How to use BufferStrategy in Java](http://gpsnippets.blogspot.no/2010/10/how-to-use-bufferstrategy-in-java.html) for a start.

**EDIT**

Out of curiosity, I did some experiments using the ideas found in the blog post above, and while the animation became quite smooth, I did not achieve full vsync using Java 6 on OS X. I still get some "tearing". This was quite a disappointment.