# Why does Canvas as contentPane not paint opaque components that are added to the JFrame glasspane

Tags: java, swing, opacity, glasspane, java-canvas

Okay I have a `Canvas` (I am using this because it can implement `BufferedStrategy`).

I add my `Canvas` to my `JFrame` *contentPane* and than add `HUDPanel` ( which is a `JPanel` consisting of 2 other `JPanel`s - with `JProgressBar`s and `JLabel`s - to show health and *chakara* bars) to my `JFrame`s *glassPane*.

All of the components on HUD are opaque.

Now when I add the `HUDPanel` to my `JFrame`s *glassPane* with a `Canvas` as its *contentPane* the 2 `JPanel`s which hold components are not painted opaque:

[image]

But if I add a `JPanel` instead of `Canvas` to `JFrame` *contentPane* all works fine:

[image]

Why is this?
and how can I fix it?

Thank you in advance

**HUDPanelTest.java**

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class HUDPanelTest {

    public HUDPanelTest() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new HUDPanelTest();
            }
        });
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame() {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {//testing only
                return new Dimension(800, 600);
            }
        };
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        HUDPanel hudPanel = new HUDPanel();
        frame.setGlassPane(hudPanel);
        JPanel p = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics grphcs) {
                super.paintComponent(grphcs);
                grphcs.setColor(Color.yellow);
                grphcs.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            }
        };
        Canvas c = new Canvas() {
            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics grphcs) {//for testing ONLY I actually use a BufferStrategy
                super.paint(grphcs);

                grphcs.setColor(Color.yellow);
                grphcs.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            }
        };

        frame.add(c);
        //frame.add(p);//this works as expected

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        hudPanel.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

**HUDPanel.java**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;

public class HUDPanel extends JPanel {

    HUDPanel.HealthPanel healthPanel;
    HUDPanel.ChakaraPanel chakaraPanel;

    public HUDPanel() {
        super(new BorderLayout(), true);
        setOpaque(false);

        healthPanel = new HUDPanel.HealthPanel();
        chakaraPanel = new HUDPanel.ChakaraPanel();

        initComponents();

        setHealthPlayer1(100);
        setHealthPlayer2(100);
        setChakaraPlayer1(0);
        setChakaraPlayer2(0);
        setLabelTextHealthPlayer1("Player 1 (Health):");
        setLabelTextHealthPlayer2("Player 2 (Health):");
        setLabelTextChakaraPlayer1("Player 1 (Chakara):");
        setLabelTextChakaraPlayer2("Player 2 (Chakara):");
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        add(healthPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(chakaraPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public void setHealthPlayer1(int health) {
        healthPanel.setPlayer1ProgressBarValue(health);
    }

    public void setHealthPlayer2(int health) {
        healthPanel.setPlayer2ProgressBarValue(health);
    }

    public void setChakaraPlayer1(int chakara) {
        chakaraPanel.setPlayer1ProgressBarValue(chakara);
    }

    public void setChakaraPlayer2(int chakara) {
        chakaraPanel.setPlayer2ProgressBarValue(chakara);
    }

    public void setLabelTextHealthPlayer1(String text) {
        healthPanel.setPlayer1LabelText(text);
    }

    public void setLabelTextHealthPlayer2(String text) {
        healthPanel.setPlayer2LabelText(text);
    }

    public void setLabelTextChakaraPlayer1(String text) {
        chakaraPanel.setPlayer1LabelText(text);
    }

    public void setLabelTextChakaraPlayer2(String text) {
        chakaraPanel.setPlayer2LabelText(text);
    }

    private class HealthPanel extends JPanel {

        JProgressBar player1ProgressBar = new JProgressBar();
        JProgressBar player2ProgressBar = new JProgressBar();
        JLabel player1Label = new JLabel();
        JLabel player2Label = new JLabel();

        public HealthPanel() {
            super(new GridBagLayout(), true);
            setOpaque(false);

            initComponents();
        }

        private void initComponents() {
            GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
            gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            gc.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
            //or else the anchoring wont work
            gc.weightx = 1;

            //gc.gridx = 0;//does not seem to make a difference
            //gc.gridy = 0;
            add(player1Label, gc);

            //gc.gridx = 1;
            //gc.gridy = 0;
            add(player1ProgressBar, gc);

            gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;

            //gc.gridx = 2;
            //gc.gridy = 0;
            add(player2Label, gc);

            //gc.gridx = 3;
            //gc.gridy = 0;
            add(player2ProgressBar, gc);
        }

        public void setPlayer1ProgressBarValue(int val) {
            player1ProgressBar.setValue(val);
        }

        public void setPlayer2ProgressBarValue(int val) {
            player2ProgressBar.setValue(val);
        }

        public void setPlayer2LabelText(String text) {
            player2Label.setText(text);
        }

        public void setPlayer1LabelText(String text) {
            player1Label.setText(text);
        }
    }

    private class ChakaraPanel extends JPanel {

        JProgressBar player1ProgressBar = new JProgressBar();
        JProgressBar player2ProgressBar = new JProgressBar();
        JLabel player1Label = new JLabel();
        JLabel player2Label = new JLabel();

        public ChakaraPanel() {
            super(new GridBagLayout(), true);
            setOpaque(false);

            initComponents();
        }

        private void initComponents() {
            GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
            gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            gc.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
            //or else the anchoring wont work
            gc.weightx = 1;
            gc.weighty = 1;

            //gc.gridx = 0;
            //gc.gridy = 0;
            add(player1Label, gc);

            //gc.gridx = 1;
            //gc.gridy = 0;
            add(player1ProgressBar, gc);

            gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;

            //gc.gridx = 2;
            //gc.gridy = 0;
            add(player2Label, gc);

            //gc.gridx = 3;
            //gc.gridy = 0;
            add(player2ProgressBar, gc);
        }

        public void setPlayer1ProgressBarValue(int val) {
            player1ProgressBar.setValue(val);
        }

        public void setPlayer2ProgressBarValue(int val) {
            player2ProgressBar.setValue(val);
        }

        public void setPlayer2LabelText(String text) {
            player2Label.setText(text);
        }

        public void setPlayer1LabelText(String text) {
            player1Label.setText(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `GlassPane` is lightweight, then is always behind `AWT Canvas`,
- this is quite common issue for `JLayeredPane`, `GlassPane` and Java and `3D`, `CAD/CAM`, `Open GL/Cl`, these APIs are based on `AWT Containers`
- same issue will be by using `JLayer` (lightweight container), but there you can to test `isLightWe....()` for peer from `Native OS`  and/or its resources

Comment: +1 thank you very some interesting stuff. So mKorbel to clarify would I use a `JLayeredPane` and add my `Canvas` and *Glasspane* to that? Or how would I go about fixing this problem ( please i would like to maintain using a `Canvas` for `BufferedStrategy`, implementing a `Window` would completely change my applications layout.....) due to the fact it is bad practice for use of multiple Frames

Comment: Im never to tried BufferedStrategy, I'm bothering with RepaintManager, I'm againt usage of JLayeredPane too, hard to describe some advice, but Swing Gurus always suggested that Swing containers are better for custom painting, sure there are 3D, CAD/CAM, Open GL/CL and they are required resources came from Native OS, then only usage of AWT container is one and possible way

Comment: Why not the default `BufferStrategy` on `JPanel`? Also, constructors should not invoke overridable methods.

Comment: @mKorbel but `BufferedStrategy` works great for games with fixed time step game loops hence why i really cannot change the use of canvas, without sacrificing a great gaming loop.... And restarting from scratch???? There must be some type of way? I thought about Window, but that too would change my entire game layout.... and i dont know if it would work or give similar problems

Comment: @trashgod BufferedStrategy is better than JPanel BufferedImage, gives more control ( especially because im creating a sprite game a i need full control of painting etc) see [here](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=23945.0)

Comment: @DavidKroukamp: Some instructive contrasting examples are cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2068517/230513).

Comment: @trashgod  thank you i will have a look, I really hope I can get this too work or there goes my game !! ( the BufferedStrategy game loop is complex, taking into account frames per second, and even has a method to catch up missed frames if performance drops etc) and I cant see how this will be implemented as flawlessly in JPanel

Comment: @DavidKroukamp no idea still is there [paintImmedialtelly()](http://www.javadocexamples.com/java_source/com/memoire/laos/LaosGraphics.java.html)

Comment: @Trashgod thank you solved it b using `JPanel` and repaint only by calling `setIgnoreRepaint(..)` on `JPanel`

Comment: hmmm then you decided to use Swing JPanel, I think good sensible choice

Comment: Ah, I see `setIgnoreRepaint()` is "useful…if page-flipping is used as the buffer strategy."