# This square I'm animating is leaving a trail behind it, can anyone work out why?

Tags: java, swing, animation, paintcomponent, graphic

Thanks for checking out this Question. I think I've just about scratched through my skull in frustration. 
So what I've got is a 'JFrame' containing a 'JPanel'. The 'JPanel' contains a little colored Square which is supposed to move X pixels whenever I click the window.

Well, essentially everything behaves as it should, with one exception. When the blue square moves to the right, it leaves a trail of other squares behind it. It is not supposed to leave the trail, however, when I re-size the window, the trail vanishes.

Catalyst.java

```
package Prototype;

import java.awt.*;

public class Catalyst {

public static void main(String[] args){
    World theWorldInstance = new World("Prototype", 100,100, 600,100);  /*title,xpos,ypos,width,height*/
}

}
```

World.java

```
package Prototype;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class World extends JFrame  {

Level mainPanel;    

public World(String title, int x, int y, int width, int height) {

    setTitle(title);
    setBounds(x,y,width,height);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setBackground(new Color(0x00000000));
    initLevel();

}

public void initLevel(){
    mainPanel = new Level();
    Container visibleArea = getContentPane();
    visibleArea.add(mainPanel);
    setVisible(true);
    add(mainPanel);
}



}
```

Level.java

```
package Prototype;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Level extends JPanel implements MouseListener, ActionListener {
Square x;


public Level() {
    System.out.println("This is working correctly[JPANEL Cons]");
    addMouseListener(this);
    x = new Square();
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    x.draw(g);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
    requestFocus();
    x.move();
    repaint();
    System.out.println("Focus Acquired");


}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
}
```

Square.java

```
package Prototype;

import java.awt.*;

public class Square {

private Point position;
private int size;
private final int displacement;

public Square(){
    position = new Point(10,10);
    size = 20;
    displacement = 5;

}

public void draw(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.fillRect(position.x-(size/2), position.y-(size/2), size,size );
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawRect(position.x-(size/2), position.y-(size/2), size,size );

}

public void move() {
    position.x += displacement;
}
}
```

Those are all my files. I hope I've phrased everything properly and provided all the content required. Whenever I've done something similar in the past this has never happened. I assume I'm missing something small, or I've done something stupid. If you can help me, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's another way of doing this.  You can simply call the parent object's paintComponent method to clear the panel.

Add this to your constructor in Level :

```
this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
```

And this as the first call in paintComponent:

```
super.paintComponent(g);
```

Comment: Ahha, that's interesting, didn't knew about this thingy or you can say never tried it :-) +1 though

Comment: Beautiful. Simple and elegant. Thank you.

Comment: Can't take credit for it, I learned about it somewhere in the Swing tutorials - saved me a bundle of headaches over the years.

Comment: If you have time, visit the Oracle Swing tutorials, especially the Java 2D ones, there's a bunch of hidden gems in there.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [g.clearRect(x, y, width, height)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#clearRect%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29), and provide the said coordinates, where you want the painting to be cleared from. Or  you can give the dimensions of whole of the `JPanel/JComponent` where you are drawing, though doing this keep one thing in mind, that the said drawing is not a heavy work, else too much of cleaning will put extra burden on the painting calls.

Comment: Thanks for the tip my friend. However, I just realized that I was doing my painting directly onto the bare JPanel. If I add a background picture, or an encompassing black rectangle to paint onto, then the problem solves itself :D I do appreciate your time though.

Comment: You are MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-), here watch this thread, all having wonderful working example of this thingies [BALL ANIMATION](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9852739/1057230)

Comment: @Ewald : You are MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-)