# Component must be a valid peer when I remove frame.add(Component)

Tags: java, swing, awt, bufferedimage

I have this code here for creating and drawing an array of pixels into an image:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt;

public class test extends Canvas implements Runnable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static int WIDTH = 800;
    public static int HEIGHT = 600;
    public boolean running = true;
    public int[] pixels;
    public BufferedImage img;
    public static JFrame frame;
    private Thread thread;

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        test wind = new test();
        frame = new JFrame("WINDOW");
        frame.add(wind);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        wind.init();
    }

    public void init() {
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
        img = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        pixels = ((DataBufferInt) img.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
    }

    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            render();
            try {
                thread.sleep(55);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void render() {
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null) {
            createBufferStrategy(4);
            return;
        }
        drawRect(0, 0, 150, 150);
        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, null);
        g.dispose();
        bs.show();

    }

    private void drawRect(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        for (int i = x; i < w; i++) {
            for (int j = x; j < h; j++) {
                pixels[i + j * WIDTH] = 346346;
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Why do I get "Component must be a valid peer" error when I remove the line:

```
frame.add(wind);
```

Why do I want to remove it? Because I want to create a frame using a class object (from another file) and use the code `Window myWindow = new Window()` to do exactly the same thing.

Comment: It's an era of Swing, so why you using `Canvas`, why not use the important feature of `JPanel`, which is `DoubleBuffering`, why not extend `JPanel` instead of the way old schema `Canvas` ? Moreover, why you blocking your EDT with code lines like `Thread.sleep(...)`, why not use [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for this purpose ?

Comment: @Downvoter : Any solid reason to downvote this ?

Comment: @nIcE cOw you attracted my attention: Timers and JPanel? hmmm can you show me your version of the code?

Comment: @nIcEcOw: I see no down-vote; you may have seen an  accidental click. See also [*How do I contact other users*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-do-i-contact-other-users)?

Comment: @boyd : Try any versions on this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9852739/1057230), especially by "trashgod", too good an example on the topic.

Comment: @nIcE cOw you know java well? because (if it's possible) we can make a small team...

Comment: @boyd : I am also a learner like you, just know a bit about Swing now, still learning Painting in Swing with each day. It's always a pleasure to work as a team though, happy to be a part of one :-)

Answer (score 5):

As @nIcE cOw comments, you appear to be [*Mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight Components*](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/mixing_components/). Substituting `Frame` still leaves the underlying problem: [`createBufferStrategy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Canvas.html#createBufferStrategy%28int%29) throws the exception because the `Canvas` is not displayable until added to the `Frame`, which relies on the features of the heavyweight peer component provided by the host platform. In effect you are trying to choose a `BufferStrategy` without specifying which buffer should use the strategy.

Instead, use an existing [engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_game_engines), or rely on the default buffer strategy provided by `JComponent`, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3256941/230513).

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component must have a valid peer
    at java.awt.Component$FlipBufferStrategy.createBuffers(Component.java:3843)
    at java.awt.Component$FlipBufferStrategy.(Component.java:3817)
    at java.awt.Component$FlipSubRegionBufferStrategy.(Component.java:4358)
    at java.awt.Component.createBufferStrategy(Component.java:3699)
    at java.awt.Canvas.createBufferStrategy(Canvas.java:166)
    at java.awt.Component.createBufferStrategy(Component.java:3623)
    at java.awt.Canvas.createBufferStrategy(Canvas.java:141)
    at test.render(test.java:52)
    at test.run(test.java:40)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Comment: +1, wish I knew Painting in Java, in that depth. LOL still studying this part each day as it comes :-)