# Java timer&paintcomponent issues

Tags: java, swing, timer, jpanel, paintcomponent

Hi I am trying to make a red box appear at the bottom of a JPanel .I wish for this box to move to one corner of the screen and stop and then start moving the other way,however i have been unable make the box stop the following is the code i have been working with

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class JavaApplication13 extends JPanel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame rough = new JFrame("Panamr");
        rough.setVisible(true);
        rough.setLocation(1, 1);
        rough.setSize(500, 500);
        rough.setContentPane(mamals);
    }

    public static int iomega(int x, int y) {
        if (y == 1) {
            diget = -5;
            time.stop();
        }
        if (y == 0) {
            diget = 5;
        }
        return diget;
    }
    static JavaApplication13 mamals = new JavaApplication13();

    JavaApplication13() {
        setBackground(Color.red);
    }
    static int oy = 400;
    static int ox = 200;
    static int diget;
    static Timer time = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {

        public int xy = 1;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            iomega(ox, xy);
            if (ox == 500) {
                xy = 1;
            }
            if (ox == 0) {
                xy = 0;
            }
            ox = ox - iomega(ox, oy);
            /*if(ox!=500){
            ox=ox-diget;
            if(ox==0){
            diget=-5;}
            else {
            diget=5;
            }            
            }*/
        }
    });
    boolean test = true;

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(ox, oy, 60, 60);
        time.start();
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: See also this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9849950/230513).

Answer (score 2):

your co-ordiantes for the frames/panels size is off, you should calculate this dynamically maybe, or have a `final` value. Next your xy=0 and xy=1 should be swapped like this:

```
 if (ox == 400) {//this was a larger number then the panel/frame so it went offscreen
            xy = 0;//swapped
        }
        if (ox == 0) {
           xy = 1;//swapped
        }
```