# Java - gui: adding a door

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am running a ball collision simulation, and I want to add a door somewhere along the edges of the frame, such that when a ball touches it, it disappears. What is the simplest Swing component that can give me the functionality of this door?

Comment: off the top of my head, I'm pretty sure Swing doesn't have one - you'd have to write one yourself.

Comment: Am I way off base, or could this be displayed by nothing but an image of a door?

Comment: One does not simply create moving balls in Swing...

Comment: are you sure that swing is the right thing to use for your needs?

Comment: @moeTi & Martijn: I've cited some examples [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11672630/230513).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know what…can be used to graphically represent the image of that door.

You probably want an overhead view, but you might get some ideas from this [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/subway) that animates a door opening and closing *en face*.

Addendum: As you are interested in animation, see also these [variations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9849950/230513) on a bouncing ball and this [`KineticModel`](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/kineticmodel).

Answer (score 0):

There is no Swing component that will give this functionality. You will have to write it yourself. If you need some additional directly, please post more information about what your existing ball collision program does, including some code snippets to illustrate what you have done so far.

Comment: I will do the functionality myself, I want to know  what can be the graphical element that I use to graphically represent the image of that door

Comment: @Trup If it is an image, then you probably want to use [java.awt.Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html).