# Update graphics for dots with Timer

Tags: java, swing, graphics, timer, paintcomponent

Before I ask my question I apologize for any inconsistencies. I´m fairly new at this.
I´m making a game that for now looks like this (the picture is not important):
[image: My game]

The red dots are supposed to move to the right and they do that with a timer. This works fine. The graphics does not update though so I have to drag the side of the window back and forth to see that my dots are moving. What can I do to fix this?

My paintcomponent method in my mainclass:

```
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    for (int x = 0; x < SomeInts.amount; x++){
        for (int y = 0; y < SomeInts.amount; y++){
            tile[x][y].colorBody(g, x, y);              
            Tower temp;
            for (int i = 0; i < towers.size(); i++){        
                temp = towers.get(i);
                temp.colorBody(g, tile[x][y].getSize());
                temp.guard.colorBody(g, tile[x][y].getSize());                        
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My red dot class. Also called Guard class:

```
public class Guard {
int x, y, size = 10, towerx, towery;
Timer timer;
public Guard(int towerx1, int towery1){
    towerx = towerx1;
    towery = towery1;
    x = towerx + 1;
    y = towery;
    new Timer().schedule(new MyTask(), 1000, 1000);
}

public void colorBody(Graphics g, int tilesize){
    g.setColor(new Color(255, 0, 0));
    g.fillOval(x * tilesize + tilesize / 4, y * tilesize + tilesize / 4, size, size);       
}

public class MyTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        x++;
    }
}
```

}

Thank you for your time.

Comment: probable reason is that you are updating off the EDT - use a swing.Timer, not the util version

Comment: Could you give me an example of this? It does not seem to work the same way.

Comment: @ZachariasHortén: See the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing a bit here, but I think you need to call the repaint() method to see the changes you've made.

Comment: Add a reference to `javax.swing.Timer` instead of `java.util.Timer` and you've got a champion answer ;)

Comment: The timers do not seem to work the same way. Also where should I call the repaint() method?

Comment: @ZachariasHortén : When you will use a `javax.swing.Timer`, then inside the **actionPerformed()** method for the said Timer, add a `repaint()` call, to make things visible. This [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9849950/1057230) might can prove useful, all good examples related to this thingy.