# Keeping the rectangle within JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, paintcomponent

I know I am being an idiot and that's why I can't figure it out but I am trying to paint a bunch of rectangles with randoms size and position using paintComponent. I am trying to make sure that all of them are painted within the frame. I am able to do it with the following code (snippet) but I am wondering if there is a better way to do it than me hardcoding numbers into the program. Is there a method that I should take a look at that might be what I'm looking for?

Here's the inner class that overrides the paintComponent() method:

```
class DrawPanel extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        int red = (int)(Math.random()*256);
        int blue = (int)(Math.random()*256);
        int green = (int)(Math.random()*256);

        g.setColor(new Color(red, blue, green));
        //The following 4 lines keep the rects within the frame
        //The frame is 500,500
        int ht = (int)(Math.random()*400);
        int wd = (int)(Math.random()*400);

        int x = (int)(Math.random()*100);
        int y = (int)(Math.random()*100);

        g.fillRect(x,y,ht,wd);
    }
}
```

Comment: What problems are you having? Are you sure that you want to randomize within `paintComponent(...)`, such that any time the gui is repainted for any reason, the rectangles will change. And are you sure that you don't want to call the `super.paintComponent(...)` method?

Comment: Also, shouldn't you be using the `getSize()` of the DrawPanel and not use the JFrame's size? Else you are ignoring its title bar etc...

Comment: See related examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9849950/230513).

Comment: Thanks Reimeus, Hovercraft and Lucas. The program was working as it was supposed to even before. The coding was just ugly and as you guys pointed out, a little wrong too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should base your co-ordinates & sizes on the `DrawPanel` component size. Also using [Random.nextInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) instead of `Math.random()` will make it easier to keep within range based on the current size of the panel:

```
Random random = new Random();
int ht = random.nextInt(getHeight());
int wd = random.nextInt(getWidth());

int x = random.nextInt(getWidth() - wd);
int y = random.nextInt(getHeight() - ht);
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot. I've upvoted all the other answers too since they were all helpful but this fixed the "problem".

Answer (score 4):

> I am wondering if there is a better way to do it than me hardcoding numbers into the program.

Yes there is

- call `getSize()` on the enclosing JPanel, the DrawPanel, so you can see the actual boundaries of the component that is being drawn upon. (edit: or `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` as recommended by Lucas -- 1+ to his answer!).
- Also, you will usually want to call the super's `paintComponent(...)` method within the child's override.
- Also you will usually want to do your randomization elsewhere, such as in the DrawPanel's constructor so as not to change your rectangles each time you re-size the GUI.

Comment: For his purposes, wouldn't calling getHeight() and getWidth() be better since getSize() returns a Dimension?

Comment: @Lucas: either could work well. 1+ to  your answer by the way.

Comment: True, it's slightly simpler to do it with the separate methods, but faster to do it with getSize() if you know what you're dong.

Answer (score 2):

There is a method to get the length and width of the panel you are working in.

```
getHeight();
getWidth();
```

These will return the current size of the JPanel you are working in, meaning if you resize the window it'll actually still draw them inside.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getWidth()