# I am trying to move a ball in applet using thread but its not moving

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, awt, event-dispatch-thread

I am trying to move a ball in applet using thread but its not moving. Can anyone help me out as m new to applet and proceeding for game development..for reference here is my code

```
public class ballGame extends JApplet implements Runnable
{
    int x_pos=50;
    int y_pos=100;
    int rad=10;
    Thread t;

    public void start() 
    {
        super.start();
        t=new Thread("t");
        t.start();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) 
    {
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawOval(x_pos,y_pos,2*rad,2*rad); 

        while(true)
        {
            x_pos++;

            //validate();
            repaint();

            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }//end of while
    }//end of paint()
}
```

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9852739/1057230), might be a good learning step in the given direction.

Answer (score 2):

Having an infinite loop in `paint`  means that not a single pass of the method can complete.

Also you should never call `Thread.sleep(100)` in the `paint` method. This blocks the `EDT` and degrades performance.

Instead use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to do the update and repainting work. Also I would sub-class a `JComponent` and override `paintComponent`.

Comment: Okay Reimeus...i will try using swing timer Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Swing is a single thread environment.  That is, all updates and interactions are executed within a single thread.  Swing is also **NOT** thread safe.  This means that all updates to the UI **MUST** be executed within the context of that thread (the Event Dispatching Thread or ETD).

Any code that blocks the EDT will prevent it from (amongst other things), repainting the UI and responding to input from the user.

You're paint code will NEVER update the screen, in fact it will make your application appear to "hang", as the `paint` method isn't being allowed to complete and is blocking the ETD.

It is an exception that the `paint` method will return quickly after been called and may be called repeatedly in quick succession.

Generally speaking, a `Thread` is probably a little over kill, something like a `javax.swing.Timer` would be more then suitable under these circumstances.

[image]

```
public class AnimatedBoat {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AnimatedBoat();
    }

    public AnimatedBoat() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new AnimationPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }

    public class AnimationPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage boat;
        private int xPos = 0;
        private int direction = 1;

        public AnimationPane() {
            try {
                boat = ImageIO.read(new File("boat.png"));
                Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        xPos += direction;
                        if (xPos + boat.getWidth() > getWidth()) {
                            xPos = getWidth() - boat.getWidth();
                            direction *= -1;
                        } else if (xPos < 0) {
                            xPos = 0;
                            direction *= -1;
                        }
                        repaint();
                    }

                });
                timer.setRepeats(true);
                timer.setCoalesce(true);
                timer.start();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return boat == null ? super.getPreferredSize() : new Dimension(boat.getWidth() * 4, boat.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            int y = getHeight() - boat.getHeight();
            g.drawImage(boat, xPos, y, this);

        }

    }

}
```

As a side note.  You should rarely need to override the `paint` method of a top level container like `JApplet` or `JFrame`, while there are a number of good reasons for this, the one that you're going to most interested in is the fact that they're not double buffered, meaning you are likely to see flickering as the screen is updated.

It's better to use something like `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method instead.

Take a look at

- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

For more information

nb
While I've used a `JFrame` for my example, it would be a simple matter to take the animation panel and put it into a `JApplet`, this is another reasons why you don't need/want to extend from top level containers ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can not invoke repaint() method inside paint(). And you can not organize infinitely loop inside paint() method - doing so, you are blocking drawing in your applet.

Comment: (nit picky - You "can" invoke `repaint` from within `paint`, there's nothing stopping you, but you "shouldn't" ;)) +1

Comment: @MadProgrammer Indeed, I meant exactly that you `shouldn't`. It is obvious :)

Answer (score 0):

Have the while loop inside the run method of Runnable.

**UPDATE:**

Have this in the start method.

```
t=new Thread(this);
t.start();
```

Comment: I tried placing it inside run() but still ball was not moving

Answer (score 0):

`x_pos`is an int value, thus it is passed to methods by value, not by reference. That is why, when you change its value, the value inside of your circle is not updated...

Answer (score 0):

You create a Thread without a `run()` method. This method should contain the runnable code... Furthermore, the `paint()` method is to *paint stuff, not update stuff!*

So move your while loop from the `paint()` method into the `run()` method of your thread:

```
t=new Thread("t") {
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            x_pos++;

            //validate();
            repaint();

            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }//end of while
    }
};
```

Note that `ballGame` does not require the `implement Runnable` part. As the thread you created will provide it.

Comment: Actually I have written run() and was writing while loop in that only but it was not working...Still i will try again..thanks fr ur help

Comment: I suppose you wrote the `run()` method directly in the `ballGame` class... You should put it in the `Thread` in order to add functionality to the `Thread`, otherwise it won't do a thing!

Comment: And implementing runnable is required I think otherwise run() will show error

Comment: As I said you should remove the `implements Runnable` part of your class definition.

Comment: Putting run()in thread means exactly where can u just tell me please

Comment: My answer shows how to do it: Just replace `t=new Thread("t");` with the provided code.

Comment: but t=new Thread("t") is in start method shall i write run() in it as you have written in code

Comment: Good! You really need to read upon `JApplet` and `Thread` so you know what these methods are used for!

Comment: but why the same code written inside run() didnt work can u tell

Comment: Because `JApplet` does not care about the `run()` method. It is just like any other custom method you could add to the `ballClass`.