# JPanel rendered behind the paint() method

Tags: java, swing, panel, frame, paint

I am trying to create a board game. The left side of my windows is my actual board game while on the right side I was going to have a few buttons and timers. I paint my board using the paint method but when I try to create a new JPanel thats rendered in the background. I know because I can see some black around the edges of the game.

This is my main code that creates my JFrame and calls my board class.

```
    frame.setSize(864, 480);
    frame.add(new Board());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setCursor(frame.getToolkit().createCustomCursor(new BufferedImage(3, 3, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB), new Point(0, 0), "null"));

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame.add(panel);
    panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
```

This is my code that paints the go board image. This is in my Board class

```
super.paint(g);
    s.location = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
    s.mouse = s.location.getLocation();
    s.updateBlackX(s.mouse);
    s.updateBlackY(s.mouse);
    s.updateWhiteX(s.mouse);
    s.updateWhiteY(s.mouse);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.drawImage(board, 0, 0, null);
    paintArray(g2d);
    if (turn == 1)
        g2d.drawImage(s.getBlackStone(), s.getBlackX() - f.getX() - 15, s.getBlackY() - f.getY() - 35, null);
    else
        g2d.drawImage(s.getWhiteStone(), s.getWhiteX() - f.getX() - 15, s.getWhiteY() - f.getY() - 35, null);
```

This is my game during run-time with further explanation as to my problem.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNuy7.jpg

Thank you in advance for any and all help!

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to create a board game. The left side of my windows is my actual board game while on the right side I was going to have a few buttons and timers.

Create two panels, one for the Board class and the other for the buttons then add them to the frame as follows:

```
frame.add(gamePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

That is don't try to do all you custom painting and game playing on a single panel.

Comment: I don't have a panel for my game board, I use awt to paint that. I add my board to my frame.

Comment: @camickr's suggested approach is worth pursuing; here's a related example is shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9852739/230513).

Comment: @user2457344 Exactly HOW do you use `paint`.  Sounds like you're abusing the paint process.  Additionally, you shouldn't be using `MouseInfo.getPointerInfo()` as it returns the point relative to the screen, not the component. Instead you should be using `MouseListener`