# Can we add shadow effects in Java swing?

Tags: java, swing

What code shall I use to add shadow effects to a panel in Java swing, I know the same is available in javafx but can we do the same in swing?

Comment: This question is too broad

Comment: I haven't tried yet and expect the answer to be 'no' but still there might be some way

Comment: Can anyone point out where my question went wrong? Have I asked something baseless?

Comment: Regarding why people don't like this question, see a note in my answer. It is not really terrible, but I personally hesitated whether to flag it as too broad or as a duplicate, but decided it deserves an answer (I personally never downvote except really terrible questions but flag is another thing) .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Swing does not provide built-in capabilities for these.

You can drop shadow either by adding border or draw manually. Here are some examples for [dropping shadow from JPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13368103/jpanel-drop-shadow)

Animation is more complex, [one approach](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/Timerbasedanimation.htm) is to use timer and change properties or draw on appropriate ticks, [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21247776/java-swing-how-to-smoothly-animate-move-component) is to incorporate some library like [Timing Framework](https://java.net/projects/timingframework/pages/Home).

As a side note, you are asking two different questions in one and probably you need to do some research by yourself before posting and provide the results in the question.

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot, and by the way is my question being down voted for asking two questions in one?

Comment: More for not stating any efforts of your own and being too broad but this too. What composes a good question is also a thing that is easy to search for on StackOverflow e,g, http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. Good question usually ask for one specific thing (not how do I this or that or that), shows what author did before, with what results and what he expects from an answer. Of course "specific" should also be [reasonable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not a bunch of unrelated code asking where is the error.