# Change the RGB values of an existing color?

Tags: java, variables, colors, rgb

I was recently trying to make a light "guess the color" game (my first one), where you get a hex code and you get some alternative to choose from. The way I've done it I need to collect information about these alternatives (which are just colored ovals). Anyway, I need to change the RGB values of a color since they are randomly generated, and it doesn't seem very efficient to create (10 in this case) separate colors and set them one at a time.

My problem is, I can not find a way to change the RGB values of my colors. Basically I created a color array (I noticed this problem exists without the array aswell) but trying to change values as you would with a normal variable doesn't work. It just gives me an error.

This is the specific method.

```
public void OvalData(int r, int b, int g, int x, int i){
    //Create two arrays containing the information
    Color OvalColor[] = new Color[difficulty];
    int[] posX = new int[difficulty];
    //Set the infromation
    Color[i] = (r, g, b);
    posX[i] = x;
```

Where this is the problem line:

```
   `Color[i] = (r, g, b);`
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Use a [color look-up table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colour_look-up_table), seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9852739/230513).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Color[i]=...` can't work at all, because `Color` is the name of the class, not your variable. What you want to change is `OvalColor[i]`, not `Color[i]`.

You could try `OvalColor[i]=new Color(r, g, b)` to assign to one of your colors, but i guess there's more than that to fix; `OvalColor` probably shouldn't be local to the `OvalData()` method.

Not related to your problem, but to your coding style: Please use initial Caps for class names only, and initial lowercase for variable and method names, like `ovalColor` or `public void ovalData(...)`. This makes problems like the one you're having much easier to spot - you'll get used to "Assigning to something hat has an initial capital letter won't work" after a while.

Comment: I see the first part of the problem, thank you :)
Yes, I was probably going to realize that it shouldn't be local sooner or later, I am quite new to this.
But just trying to understand, I should just create new colors instead of trying to change the existing ones?

I'll try to change how I write. I'm always looking to improve!