# Is it possible to make my JFrame button to constantly prints outputs

Tags: java, swing, debugging, concurrency, jframe

What the program is supposed to do:
Has a OK BUTTON: outputs the users time every 1000ms
Has a CLOSE button: stops the OK BUTTON and have no outputs

Is it possible to make my actionlistener for my button "Ok" to keep on going without a while loop? I'm trying to make it so u can click once, and every other button can still work in my JFrame.

What i mean by this is, whenever you place the while loop inside the action listener, it ignores all inputs to a different button, and i can't stop it unless i completely delete the program. So, is it possible just to make my program keep running as if it was a while loop but can be stopped with the "Close" button i had made in the program?

```
package com.mc.main;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;  
import java.time.LocalDateTime;   
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class GetTime {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JLabel headerLabel;
    private JLabel statusLabel;
    private JPanel controlPanel;
    static String usersTimeNow;
    public GetTime() {
        prepareGUI();
        
    }
       private void prepareGUI(){
              frame = new JFrame("Java Swing");
              frame.setSize(500,500);
              frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
              frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
              frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                 public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent){
                    System.exit(0);
                 }
              });
              headerLabel = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);
              statusLabel = new JLabel("",JLabel.CENTER);
              statusLabel.setSize(350,100);
              controlPanel = new JPanel();
              controlPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
              frame.add(headerLabel);
              frame.add(controlPanel);
              frame.add(statusLabel);
              frame.setVisible(true);
           }
           private void showButtonDemo(){
              boolean isStopped = false; 
              headerLabel.setText("Button Demo");
              JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
              okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    
                     getUsersTime();
                     sleepDelay();
                     
                 }
              });
              controlPanel.add(okButton);
              frame.setVisible(true);
              
              JButton closeButton = new JButton("CLOSE");
              closeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    frame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
                }
              });
              controlPanel.add(closeButton);
              frame.setVisible(true);
              
           }
    public void getUsersTime() {
           DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");  
           LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();  
           System.out.println(dtf.format(now));  
           usersTimeNow = dtf.format(now);
           statusLabel.setText(usersTimeNow);

    }
    public void sleepDelay() {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GetTime test = new GetTime();
        test.showButtonDemo();
        
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try using a timer instead. Import javax.swing.Timer;

```
Timer t = new Timer(1000, (ActionEvent e)->{
//here is where you would put what you want to happen every 1000 milliseconds


});
```

Then you can make a button that when pressed you call:

```
t.start();
```

and for the close button:

```
t.stop();
```

Comment: (1+) See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25084248/no-delay-in-gui-execution-even-after-implementing-sleep-in-a-separate-thread/25084314#25084314 for a basic Timer example.

Answer (score 0):

Your complete code would be

```
package com.mc.main;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
public class GetTime {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JLabel headerLabel;
    private JLabel statusLabel;
    private JPanel controlPanel;
    static String usersTimeNow;
    public LocalDateTime now;
    public static Timer t;
    public GetTime() {
        prepareGUI();
        
    }
       private void prepareGUI(){
              frame = new JFrame("Java Swing");
         t = new Timer(1000,(ActionEvent e)-> {
             DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");  
             now = LocalDateTime.now();
             System.out.println(dtf.format(now));  
             usersTimeNow = dtf.format(now);
           
             statusLabel.setText(usersTimeNow);
                
            });
              frame.setSize(500,500);
              frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
              frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
              frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                 public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent){
                    System.exit(0);
                 }
              });
              headerLabel = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);
              statusLabel = new JLabel("",JLabel.CENTER);
              statusLabel.setSize(350,100);
              controlPanel = new JPanel();
              controlPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
              frame.add(headerLabel);
              frame.add(controlPanel);
              frame.add(statusLabel);
              frame.setVisible(true);
           }
           private void showButtonDemo(){
              boolean isStopped = false; 
              headerLabel.setText("Button Demo");
              JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
              okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    
                     getUsersTime();
                     sleepDelay();
                     
                 }
              });
              controlPanel.add(okButton);
              frame.setVisible(true);
              
              JButton closeButton = new JButton("CLOSE");
              closeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                   t.stop();
                    // frame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
                }
              });
              controlPanel.add(closeButton);
              frame.setVisible(true);
              
           }
    public void getUsersTime() {
        t.start();  
        
           
    }
    public void sleepDelay() {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GetTime test = new GetTime();
        test.showButtonDemo();
        
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: (1-) Don't create a new answer for the code. The code should be part of your original answer.