# How do I use JButton to stop a 'while-loop'

Tags: java, swing

To learn some JAVA.
I have created a simple SwingUI, a frame and a button.
It should return System.out loop every 2 seconds.
The button would then stop the loop.
But it seems to freeze.. *go figure*

I would like some help on this.
I do have some books here mostly 'dummies', if you can point out the topic or book title I should read.
I would be grateful. Thanks.

```
/**
 * A basic JFrame with a button to stop 'while-loop'
 */
public class TestCode {

    private boolean runLoop;

    public void initFrameUI() {
        // create frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLayout(null);

        // create button
        JButton button = new JButton();
        frame.add(button);
        button.setBounds(60, 60, 90, 30);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            // button click event
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                runLoop = false;
            }
        });
    }

    public void printLoop() {
        while (runLoop) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                System.out.println("Loop-da-loop");
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(TestCode.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // just a start point
        new TestCode();
    }

    public TestCode() {
        // constructor for JFrame
        initFrameUI();
        
        // start the loop
        runLoop = true;
        printLoop();
    }
}
```

Comment: *I do have some books here mostly 'dummies'* - well, if those books teach you to use a null layout then you should definitely throw them in the garbage. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. *if you can point out the topic or book* - read the [Swing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for all Swing basics. Start with the sections on `Layout Mangers` and `How to Use Timers`. Use the Timer to replace your looping code. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25084314/131872 for a basic example that does what you want. Also read the section on `Concurrency`.

Comment: Dummies all-in-one is a reference book, it does have a topic on Concurrency, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, your code is blocking the *main thread*. A thread is essentially responsible for executing your code and there can be multiple threads running at the same time.
The *main thread* is the thread executing your code when your program starts, that is, the thread which executes the `main(String[])` method.

Now, the main thread is responsible for updating the UI and reacting to events, like when the user presses a button. However, in your case, the main thread is stuck in the method `printLoop()` and never gets to chance to react to a pressed button. (It does check the variable *runLoop*, however it is also responsible for executing the ActionListener which sets this variable to false. But this never happens here.)

What you could do is have a different thread take care of repeatedly printing to the console:

```
/**
 * A basic JFrame with a button to stop 'while-loop'
 */
public class TestCode {

    private boolean runLoop;

    public void initFrameUI() {
        // create frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLayout(null);

        // create button
        JButton button = new JButton();
        frame.add(button);
        button.setBounds(60, 60, 90, 30);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            // button click event
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                runLoop = false;
            }
        });
    }

    public void printLoop() {
        while (runLoop) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                System.out.println("Loop-da-loop");
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(TestCode.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // just a start point
        new TestCode();
    }

    public TestCode() {
        // constructor for JFrame
        initFrameUI();
        
        // start the loop
        runLoop = true;
        // Have a different thread call printLoop() so the main thread can handle button presses
        new Thread(this::printLoop).start();
    }
}
```

If you are unfamiliar with working with multiple threads, you should take a look into that before using it frequently, because there are lots of things that can go wrong.