# Timer in Java Swing (pause/reset/start)

Tags: java, swing, timer

I have this current code written in my program that is supposed to start the timer, however the code does not work. The timer does not start and I'm pretty sure that I missed something out.

```
private Timer timer; 

private void StartStopTimerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               

    timer = new Timer(5000,new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

        }
    });

    StartStopTimer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (!timer.isRunning()) {
                timer.start(); AddOneActionPerformed(evt);
            } else {
                timer.stop();
            }
        } 
    });
}
```

The private class is right at the top of my program and the rest of the code is located in a button.

Comment: You're creating a Timer object inside of the StartStopTimerActionPerformed method, but the Timer does nothing, has an empty actionPerformed method and is never started. Then you're adding an ActionListener to some entity (another Timer?) but not starting it. Have you gone through the [Swing Timer tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) on this?

Comment: Please consider creating and posting a small but simple complete program that illustrates your problem, an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please check the link for the details of this very useful tool.

Comment: Every time StartStopTimerActionPerformed is called, you create another instance of Timer, and then add another ActionListener  to StartStopTimer...Consider providing a runnable example which demonstrates your problem

Comment: There's a complete example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9852739/230513).