# Java graphic not painting properly

Tags: java, swing

I've written the following code

```
   import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

final public class Test
{

    JFrame frame;
    DrawPanel drawPanel;
    boolean up = false;
    boolean down = true;
    boolean left = false;
    boolean right = true;
    private int timeStep = 0;
    private int ballYTravel = 100;
    private int BALL_NUM = 24;

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        new Test().go();
    }

    private void go()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        drawPanel = new DrawPanel();

        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, drawPanel);

        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        moveIt();
    }

    class DrawPanel extends JPanel
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public double getY(int i, int t) {
            return 200 + ballYTravel / 2 * (Math.sin(timeStep * (i / 200 + 0.08)));
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {    
            for (int k = 0; k < BALL_NUM; k++ ) {
                g.fillRect(100  + 20 *k , (int) getY(k, timeStep), 6, 6);
            }
            timeStep++;

        }
    }



    private void moveIt()
    {
        while (true)
        {

            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            frame.repaint();
        }
    }
    }
```

It runs and animates, however it is not animating in the same fashion as the Javascript code I referenced it from which can be found here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYQoQZ

any help in understanding why is appreciated

Comment: `"...however it is not animating in the same fashion..."` -- can you be a bit more descriptive?

Comment: Note -- you should use a Swing Timer to drive your animation, not a while-true loop with Thread.sleep. That way spells threading disaster.

Comment: The link can be found in the [swing info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info) tab.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels the aniamtion present in the Swing application simply moves up and down, while the Javascript version with almost identical code (look at the codepen) move about on both axis

Comment: You need to get all animation code out of paintComponent and into your [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). The paintComponent method should just paint the ball once and that's it, without a for loop (unless you're drawing multiple balls simultaneously). Also see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9849950).

Comment: Is your goal to draw 12 balls? If so, then keep your for loop. Note A) that there is no code present that would give your animation any x-axis translation, i.e., you have no `getX(...)` method, B) javascript animation is done completely differently and so you can't borrow code from JS and use it in Swing. Also, please clarify just what animation effect you're trying to achieve.

Comment: A working example and several variations are examined in this possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9849950/230513).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: D'oh, I should have looked under "Linked." :-)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels What do you mean clarify? I'm trying to achive the same animation effect as the codepen I linked. I put the code into a Swing Timer and the effects are still the same. Also I don't need a getX, which is visible in the code, the x axis is 100 + 20 * k, I convered that JS code from ActionScript, I also converted it to C# and it worked alright too. There isn't any reason simple math shouldn't work with Swing.

Comment: Kudos for a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are (possibly) two basic problems...

1. In `getY`, you are ignoring the parameter `t` and using `timeStep` instead, while, technically, this probably isn't going to make a MASSIVE difference, it is an area of concern
2. You have an integer division issue.  `i/200` will result in `int` result, where you really want a `double`.  Change it to `i/200d`

For example...

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

final public class Test {

    private int timeStep = 0;
    private final int ballYTravel = 100;
    private final int BALL_NUM = 24;

    public static void main(String... args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new DrawPanel());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    class DrawPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public DrawPanel() {
            new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    timeStep++;
                    repaint();
                }
            }).start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 200);
        }

        public double getY(int i, int t) {
            return 100 + ballYTravel / 2 * (Math.sin(t * (i / 200d + 0.08)));
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            for (int k = 0; k < BALL_NUM; k++) {
                g.fillRect(10 + 20 * k, (int) getY(k, timeStep), 6, 6);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

You're also breaking the paint chain, which is going to cause you issues in the long run, make sure you are calling `super.paintComponent`...

For more details see...

- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)
- [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)
- [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)
- [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

Answer (score 5):

Your transliteration reveals several problems:

- Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manipulated *only* on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).
- Don't use `setSize()` when you really mean to override [`getPreferredSize()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513).
- Invoke `pack()` to let the container adopt its preferred size.
- Use [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to pace the animation.

Revised code, incorporating @Mad's [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27369244/230513) and using `drawOval()`:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

final public class Test {

    JFrame frame;
    DrawPanel drawPanel;
    private int timeStep = 0;
    private int ballYTravel = 100;
    private int BALL_NUM = 24;

    public static void main(String... args) {
        new Test().go();
    }

    private void go() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                drawPanel = new DrawPanel();
                frame.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, drawPanel);
                frame.setResizable(false);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                Timer t = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        drawPanel.repaint();
                    }
                });
                t.start();
            }
        });
    }

    private class DrawPanel extends JPanel {

        public double getY(int i, int t) {
            return 200 + ballYTravel / 2 * (Math.sin(t * (i / 200d + 0.08)));
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            for (int k = 0; k < BALL_NUM; k++) {
                g.drawOval(100 + 20 * k, (int) getY(k, timeStep), 8, 8);
            }
            timeStep++;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(700, 500);
        }

    }
}
```