# Can't paint on JPanel after clearRect() and repaint()

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, paint

I have a program which lets the user paint. But when the user clicks the clear button which calls clearRect() and repaint() the user can no longer keep painting on the same panel. Another issue I am having is that when the user clicks the save or open button (which open up a file explorer window), if the user presses cancel, the panel paints the file window onto the panel. How would I go about fixing these issues?

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponents(g);
    g.fillOval(myX - radius, myY - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);
    if(img != null)
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
}
```

Below portion is inside of an actionPerformed method

```
if(source == clear){
    g.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    g.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    repaint();
}
```

BufferedImage and Graphics

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(1000, 1000, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g = img.createGraphics();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the `Graphics` context, `g`, is invalid in your `ActionListener`, perhaps due to using `getGraphics()` inappropriately. Instead, let your `ActionListener` update fields in your view class and modify the `Graphics` context in `paintComponent()` using the updated values.

In this complete [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9852739/230513), the various implementations of `actionPerformed()` in the `buttonPanel` update attributes in the `DrawingArea`. The implementation of `paintComponent()` in `DrawingArea` then knows what to draw *each* time it is called.

[image]

Comment: I added the buffered image and Graphics declarations up top.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted; it looks like you were confounding a valid `Graphics` context for the `BufferedImage` with the one supplied to `paintComponent()`.